# Restrict generic email in Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am trying to find a way to stop client inputing generic email address such as (gmail, outlook) when filling a form on Salesforce community

I know that there is a way to restrict email input to match a certain pattern by doing this

```
<lightning:input type="email" label="Email"
        pattern=".+@example.com"
        placeholder="username@example.com" />
```

But in my case, it's more to restrict the input of a gmail or outlook email address.
I just want to make sure the client uses a business email when submiting a form.

I want to display an error message when the client tries to submit a form with the email field containing gmail or outlook.

Is there something similar to "pattern" that*emphasized text* would solve my issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can display a custom error message with setCustomValidity() and reportValidity() if email contains 'gmail' or 'outlook'.

Below is the code example:

**.html:**

```
 <aura:component>
      <lightning:input type="email" label="Email" aura:id=="inputEmail" placeholder="username@example.com"/>
      <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{! c.onEmailSave}" />
</aura:component>
```

**.js:**

```
onEmailSave: function(component, event) {
   var inputCmp = component.find(".inputEmail");
   var email= inputCmp.get("v.value");
    if(email){
       if(email.includes("gmail") || email.includes("outlook")){
          inputCmp.setCustomValidity("your custom error message");
       }
       else{
          inputCmp.setCustomValidity(""); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
       }
     }
    inputCmp.reportValidity();          
 }
```

You can learn more about custom error message [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation)